# Multiple Download/Upload parallely in FTP using C#

Tags: c#

I want to do Multiple Download/Upload parallely in FTP using C# without using FTPWebRequest.
I have written my custom code and when i try to download two files simultaneously first one get download properly while second one shows size as 0 KB(it also downloads).

```
public void sendCommand(String command, params string[] strfilename)
{
    if (command == "RETR ") //Downloading file from Server
    {


        FileStream output = null;
        if (!File.Exists(strfilename[0]))
        output = File.Create(strfilename[0]);

        else
        output = new FileStream(strfilename[0] , FileMode.Open);

        command = "RETR " + strfilename[0];

        Byte[] cmdBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((command + "\r\n").ToCharArray());
        clientSocket.Send(cmdBytes, cmdBytes.Length, 0);
        Socket csocket = createDataSocket();

        DateTime timeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(this.timeoutSeconds);

        while (timeout > DateTime.Now)
        {
            this.bytes = csocket.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, 0);
            output.Write(this.buffer, 0, this.bytes);

            if (this.bytes <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        //  this.BinaryMode = true;
        output.Close();

        if (csocket.Connected) csocket.Close();

        this.readResponse();
        MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded successfully");  

        else if....so on

    }
}
```

In my main method i do like this:

```
ftpcommand.sendCommand("RETR ","RMSViewer.xml"); //Downloading from Server
ftpcommand.sendCommand("RETR ","cms.xml");//Downloading from Server
```

Any code snippet....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave said, you'd need separate instances of your ftpCommand class.  Look into use the BackgroundWorker to run the commands in the background (asynchronously).

Comment: @Patrick :So if there are 100 files i have to create 100 instaces ?

Comment: I doubt you'd be able to download 100 files simultaneously -- most FTP servers put a limit to the number of connections a single IP can make (to prevent a single person from overloading the server).  Your original question asked about downloading two files simultaneously.  With two different instances of your ftpCommand class and a couple of BackgroundWorker classes, it is doable.

Comment: @Patrick : 2 instances ? Can you pls tell me where to create 2 instance in my above code.Thanks.

Comment: No, I can't since your code only shows a single method.  Look back in your code where the "ftpcommand" is created.  That's where you'll want to create multiple instances and have them execute on a separate thread (i.e. BackgroundWorker).

Comment: @Patrick :  FTPCommand ftpcommand = new FTPCommand(ServerAddress, UserName, Password);
                 ftpcommand.Login();
                 ftpcommand.sendCommand("CWD ", "/home/praveena/RMS");  
                 ftpcommand.sendCommand("PASV");
                  //ftpcommand.sendCommand("NLST *", 
                 //ftpcommand.sendCommand("NLST *");  //Directory Listing   
                 ftpcommand.sendCommand("STOR ", "FTP.pdf");
 ftpcommand.sendCommand("STOR ", "Linux.pdf");
 ftpcommand.sendCommand("QUIT");

Here you mean to say ?

Comment: How to do upload/download parallely in FTP using C# ? Now when i am doing multiple upload it happens one after the other i want o do it parallely

Comment: Research the BackgroundWorker class.  It will let you do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How are you issuing your requests simultaneously?

Threaded?

If so - you may want to ensure you're creating separate instances of your "ftpcommand" class.

I think we'll need more information to be able to help you :)

Comment: Ya Like i want to know how i can create thread on it for simultaneous requests.Sepearte instance means i didn't get you . i am using like this

 ftpcommand.sendCommand("RETR ","RMSViewer.xml");//Downloading from Server              
                ftpcommand.sendCommand("RETR ","cms.xml");//Downloading from Server