# How to do multiple Upload/Download in FTP using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, ftp, ftpwebrequest

How to do multiple Upload/Download in FTP using C# without using FtpWebRequest ?

I have an idea it can be achieved using threads, but i am not able to begin.

If any body has some code snippet for reference for doing multiple Upload/download in FTP using threads, it will be helpful.

Comment: So, your actual question is: 'How do I do multi-threading in C#'?

Comment: May be. I am new to threading .Ca you pls provide me some code snippet which can solve my purpose..

Comment: possible duplicate of:  
[How to do multiple FTP Uploads/Downloads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368571/how-to-do-multiple-ftp-uploads-downloads)  
[Multiple Download/Upload in FTP using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362039/multiple-download-upload-in-ftp-using-c)

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369930/how-to-do-multiple-upload-download-in-a-single-connection-in-ftp-using-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368571/how-to-do-multiple-ftp-uploads-downloads

Answer (score 1):

Might be this is of any help.

<>http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial179_Creating-a-download-manager-in-Csharp.html
<>ssshttp://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/259544-Making-download-manager.aspx

Plus you can try to use sockets to get files from FTP server. I'm not really sure how can you do uploads with

Also take a look at this:
http://www.techfundu.com/2010010980/microsoft-technology/net-technologies/c-ftp-client-in-secure-mode