# How to do multiple Upload/Download in a single connection in FTP using C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to do multiple FTP Uploads/Downloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368571/how-to-do-multiple-ftp-uploads-downloads)
>   [Multiple Download/Upload in FTP using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362039/multiple-download-upload-in-ftp-using-c)

How to do multiple Upload/Download in a single connection in FTP using C#?
I dont want to use FTPWebRequest because maybe at some later stage I'll need to convert this code to C++

Any code snippet ..

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369886/how-to-do-multiple-upload-download-in-ftp-using-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368571/how-to-do-multiple-ftp-uploads-downloads

Comment: Have some patience. Asking the same question several times over and over will not help.

Comment: Oded is right... You've asked the same question 4 times!  If you're not getting the response you are looking for, you should edit your question, not re-ask it again... and again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Managed C++, you'll still be able to use FTPWebRequest? If you're not, the code will be so *completley* different, unless you P/Invoke out to do everything that you'll spend more time *trying* to translate your C# into C++ than you'd save by just re-writing it from scratch.

In short, if you're targeting the CLR, use FTPWebRequest no matter what language you're targeting. If you're targeting native code with C++, use a library of your choice or OS native methods.